# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR after adding certbot SSL on nginx

Tags: node.js, deployment, ssl-certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy, certbot

I configured Nginx and my website was working correctly on HTTP but since I am using *react-webcam* and it needs secure connection (HTTPS) to access camera, I had to add SSL.

- My stack is MERN
- Domain is from GoDaddy
- Deployed on Digital Ocean droplet
- Server is Nginx

and I add SSL using **certbot on nginx** but right after that my website stopped working and giving me following error:

`net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I am not sure why is it happening,

- Is it because certbot SSL on Nginx ?
- Is it the way I am accessing my server from react using `https://mywebsite.info:8080` ?

I have already spent 2 days trying to figure out but can't. Please any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Port 8080 by convention is HTTP. 2) Are you saying that you added SSL on port 8080? 3) Which port is configured for HTTP? 3) Show those details in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for replying but I found the problem! I added proxy_pass on port 8080 and as I added SSL, the requests from frontend start going to 443 (the default port of https), but I was calling endpoint at 8080 from frontend which was not the case after adding SSL, so I just removed 8080 port from frontend api call and it works fine